# How to calculate the total charge separated by the Hall effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, charge, hall-effect

If a plate is undergoing the Hall Effect, how can we calculate the total charge $Q$ present on either side of the plate at the equilibrium state?

And how can we calculate the force that such a charge will exert on an external charged particle at distance $X$ from the positive surface of the plate?

[image: Visual Illustration of the question]

Comment: I think the problem here is that *ALL* the charged particles (the whole charge in the current) are deviated from their course but they are deviated more or less according to the strength of the magnetic field at their location. Thus it makes more sense to talk about an electric field $\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$ (from the equilibrium) created by the Hall effect than a total amount of charge that wouldn't depend on the distance the charge is deviated by.

Comment: The Electric field (as far as I understand) exists between the positively charged surface and the negatively charged surface. That doesn't exactly affect the external charged particle if I understand correctly.

Comment: Separated charges induce a electric field in the whole universe which can be neglected at locations very far away from the charges because the electric field is proportional to the inverse square of the distance to the charged particles
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\sum_{i=1}^2\int_{A_i} \sigma(\mathbf{r'})\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|^3}dA',
$$
where $\sigma(\mathbf{r'})$ is the charge density of the charges on the surfaces of the plate you are considering: $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: And from there, would the force on the particle just be the force due to an electric field given by 
$$F = qE$$

also, wouldn't $ σ(r′) $ be equal to $ \frac{Q}{A} $ where $ A = Ld $  , making the need to calculate $Q$ still present?

Comment: This was just a reminder that the electric field is not only between the plates... In this case there should be a way to calculate it more easily. Maybe you could calculate the average diversion by which the charge flow is deviated with the Hall effect by setting the lorentz force ($q_0\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$) equal to the electric force in the form $\frac{q_0^2}{4\pi\epsilon r^2}$ (instead of $q_0\mathbf{E}$) and solve for r. And then you would have the Volume $V=rLw$ of charged particles that was "pushed to the edge". For the charge youd need to know $Q/V$ tho. Maybe from $I=\int j dA$?

Comment: Shouldn't the volume be $V = rLd$ (instead of $ V = rLw $ )? Since the charges deviated along the $w$ side and settled on the face $ A = Ld $, making $r$ be a value along the $w$ axis?

Also, for $ I = \int j dA $ , $ j $ represents the current density, as far as I understand. If I provide the $ I $ as an input, would getting $ j $ be as simple as $ j = \frac{I}{A} $ ? And how can I get $ Q $ from $ j $?

Comment: Yes $V=rLd$ (Typo). If $j$ is constant on $A$ then yes $j=\frac{I}{A}$. I'm not sure how to get Q. I was just "thinking out loud".